# actionFunction working only when I have certain parameters in the URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I am having a weird issue when using apex:actionFunction as it only works sometimes (Only when I am passing a parameter in the URL). The visualforce page sometimes will have a parameter in the url, and sometimes it might not have. if it has the parameter it renders the information from an object and when it is click save it update the record, however if it doesnt have this parameter it creates a new record.

the following code only works if there is a valid parameter in the URL, if it doesnt have a parameter it does nothing.

I have on the header the following javascript that calls the actionfunction when the dropdown is change

```
function callControllerMethod(){        
    var value1 = document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.BillingState}").value;
    callControllerMethod2(value1);
}
```

This is what I have in my dropdown:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callControllerMethod2" action="{!calendarValue}" reRender="result" >
    <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!value1}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
<apex:outputPanel id="result" >
   {!calendar}
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:selectList value="{!BillingState}" id="BillingState" size="1" onchange="callControllerMethod()" >
    <apex:selectoption itemLabel="" itemValue=""></apex:selectoption>
    <apex:selectoption itemLabel="NSW" itemValue="NSW"></apex:selectoption>
    <apex:selectoption itemLabel="WA" itemValue="WA"></apex:selectoption>
    <apex:selectoption itemLabel="QLD" itemValue="QLD"></apex:selectoption>
</apex:selectList>
```

I have also add a system.debug in the function that is called "calendarValue" but this debug doesnt display anything (USER_DEBUG) when i test the VF page without a parameter

```
public void calendarValue (){
    System.debug('in the function');
    calendar = 'c1' + value1;        
}
```

Is there anything that I missing when using apex:actionFunction ?

**EDIT**

I have a method to access the parameters that is called when the page load:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" action="{!pageInitialParams}"  sidebar="false" showHeader="false" cache="false" controller="FormExxpert" standardStylesheets="false">
```

this function has as a main objective to check if the id in the URL is Valid if yes, it does a query an assign the result to a group of global variables. that I have declared like:

```
public String valuexxx{get;set;}
```

The save method it just check if one of those global variables is not blank an does an insert or an update.

**EDIT 2**

I also notice something that make it even more weird:
I have in the form a couple of fields that are required="true", if I submit the form having one of this fields empty then if I select the state it works fine.

Comment: What value comes when you alert(value1); in java script function when user select any value in drop down? Does is display same value that you have selected in drop down?

Comment: It actually comes with the right value, so if you select NSW it comes with NSW, this is in both the url with and without params

Comment: Better if you can post your controller constructor or wherever you are accessing the URL parameters.

Comment: I have write a short edit to explain what the main 2 methods does, but both of them works fine so I am not sure to paste as the VF page is really long

Comment: It might sound silly, but put an `<apex:pageMessages>` element on your page in an outputPanel that's also rerendered as part of the actionFunction.

Comment: well i already have an apex:pagemessage at the beginning of the form, so you mean to add another one in the section of the output pannel were i am displaying the result (when the method is called?)

Comment: Just add the id to the rerender attribute of the actionfunction - that way any errors will be surfaced when the actionfunction executes.

Answer (score 2):

Using an action function this way definitely works - I've produced a dwindled down version of your code in my dev org.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AFTry 
{
    public String afParam {get; set;}
    public String billingState {get; set;}

    public void AF()
    {
        System.debug('### In AF, param = ' + afParam);
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="AFTry">
  <apex:form id="form">
    <apex:actionFunction name="af" action="{!AF}" rerender="selected">
      <apex:param name="value1" assignTo="{!afParam}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:selectList value="{!BillingState}" id="BillingState" size="1" onchange="callControllerMethod()" >
        <apex:selectoption itemLabel="" itemValue=""></apex:selectoption>
        <apex:selectoption itemLabel="NSW" itemValue="NSW"></apex:selectoption>
        <apex:selectoption itemLabel="WA" itemValue="WA"></apex:selectoption>
        <apex:selectoption itemLabel="QLD" itemValue="QLD"></apex:selectoption>
    </apex:selectList>  
    <apex:outputPanel id="selected">
        {!afParam}
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
  <script>
function callControllerMethod(){        
    var value1 = document.getElementById("{!$Component.form.BillingState}").value;
    af(value1);
}    
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

When I choose any value, including the blank, the system.debug statement executes correctly:

> 08:47:51:047 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|### In AF, param = NSW
>
> ...
>
> 08:48:05:039 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|### In AF, param =

The lack of the debug output when you choose the blank value implies the action method isn't being executed, which usually means an error has occurred as part of the postback.  The best way to tackle this is to add an apex:pageMessages component and add the id of that to the rerender attribute on your actionfunction.  I wrote a blog post a while ago on this at:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/the-importance-of-page-messages.html

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you for your reply, that is exactly what I have but the problem is not when the blank option is selected, the problem is when i am not passing any params in the URL. When there is a param it works fine, but when there is not a param, the actionfunction doesnt seem to be calling the method, what is weird is that if i check on firebug, in the console, I can see a post

Comment: Have you added the apex:pagemessages?  It sounds like you have an error being swallowed to me.

Comment: I have add a small description in Edit 2, as if i submit the form and it fails because of am empty required field, then it works fine

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine" - are you saying the postback for the actionfunction completes even though there are missing required fields?

Comment: Sorry for confusion it only works when there is a param in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Add another action function with no param that is expressly used to clear the value on the controller if the param is not present.

You can check for the presence of the param with `$CurrentPage.parameters.firstParam` in your JavaScript precall function.

Perhaps not that elegant, but it should get the job done until you figure out what is going on.